# Why is datatables concatenating data?

Tags: datatables

I have the following code:

```
var {$js_key} = this.api().columns($i);

var {$js_key}_select = $('<select><option value="">$please</option></select>')
.appendTo($appendTo)
.on('change', function () {
    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
        $(this).val()
    );

    {$js_key}.search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false ).draw();
});                 

{$js_key}.data().each(function(d,j){
    alert(d);
})
```

d should clearly be each instance of the data. Instead I'm getting:
`Yes,No,No,No,No,No,No,No`. What have I done wrong? I should be able to output each option and fyi this is the *whole* value of the Select box so is not just an issue with alert/outputting.

I'm using v 1.10.12 and its jquery.datatables.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after further investigations - this was because I was using the columns() function and should have used column()!!

https://datatables.net/reference/api/column()

Hope that helps anyone else.